# InfluxDB & Grafana Cross domain error

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I receive the following error when i try to access InfluxDB admin UI or via Graphana:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://54.zzz.xx.yyy:8086/cluster_admins/authenticate?u=abc&p=dec. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

Note that I get this error only when I try to connect via Internet, when I go to the servers local network and change the public IP mentioned above to local IP, everything works.

Now I understand what is cross-domain error and CORS, I also get that I need to enable CORS as the error says in InfluxDB server, point is I don't know how to do that.

InfluxDB is on a Ubuntu server 14.something on AWS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since nobody answered, I resorted to my backup option, used IIS as a proxy which internally reads from local intranet and hence avoids the cross-domain error.

Details at: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-(arr)/creating-a-forward-proxy-using-application-request-routing

You can use Apache or any other web server which has URL rewriting capabilities, in my case I used IIS.

Edit:
Turns out its hard coded for now and will be changed later: https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb/issues/1244#issuecomment-68219522

Answer (score 0):

Although this is already answered, I would like to share my solution for an Angular app accessing InfluxDB using docker and Apache as a reverse proxy. With this setup you can make requests to `InfluxDB` from `localhost:4200` via `http://localhost:8080/query?[..]`.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  apache:
    image: bitnami/apache:2.4
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./apache/influxdb_proxy.conf:/vhosts/influxdb_proxy.conf:ro
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:1.7
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    volumes:
      - ./influxdb/data:/var/lib/influxdb
```

**apache/influxdb_proxy.conf**

```
ProxyPass / http://influxdb:8086/
ProxyPassReverse / http://influxdb:8086/

Header set  Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:4200"
```